# issue with droppable option jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Here is my code:

```
$('.canDrag').draggable({
            revert:'invalid',
            snap:'.dropSpace',
            cursor:'move',
            start:function() {
                $(this).addClass('currentDrag');
            }
        });
```

This is sets the draggable elements and attaches a function to the `start` event.
This is the `droppable` code:

```
$('.trashSpace').droppable({

            drop:function() {
                $('.currentDrag').remove();
            },
        });
```

To clarify, I'm trying to make a 'trash' section of the document where elements disappear when dropped in. I've set a `currentDrag` class to the draggable and set the drop function to `remove` the `currentDrag` class when dropped. But the remove is not happening. Please help.

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/q59CU/), with or without comma.

Comment: @minitech Works fine with Chrome and Firefox, but god knows what can an extra comma do with IE or other special browsers :).

Comment: @minitech--in my original code i have another option after drop, so the comma isnt really 'extra'... that being said my example should be the same as yours but mine still doesnt work. any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra comma in the `droppable` code.

```
$('.trashSpace').droppable({
  drop:function() {
    $('.currentDrag').remove();
  }, // <-- here
});
```

I tested the code using jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery 1.8.13 and it is working.

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/izuhej/2/edit)** is the code.

Comment: @dzejkej---in my original code i have another option after drop, so the comma isnt really 'extra'... that being said my example should be the same as yours but mine still doesnt work. any other thoughts?

Comment: @codeninja Then I guess the problem is somewhere else in your code or you are using different version of jQuery UI that has bugs in D&D. Can you please link your page or post the code that is not working for you on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com ?